# CSS Pointer-events css property on safari 5

Tags: javascript, css, svg, safari, cross-browser

Is it possible to allow interaction on controls bellow SVG tag on safari 5 browser?

Following [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fx4Ws/4/) works on firefox and chrome (win) but not on safari 5 (mac).

With invisible rectangle I attempted to solve the problem on safari 5 with no success.

Here is the code:

```
<div class='divC'>
   <input type="text" name="input" value="Type here">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="200" height="200" >
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="180" height="180" opacity='0' pointer-events="none"  />
  <rect x="50" y="50" width="50" height="50" />
  <rect id='rc' x="50" y="120" width="50" height="50"  />

</svg>

svg { border:solid 1px green; position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px; pointer-events:none;}
rect#rc {
  fill: red;
  pointer-events:visible;
}

rect#rc:hover {
  fill: green;
}
```

I want to be able to interact with text box that is underneath the SVG, is that possible?

Edit:
Raising input control with z-index is not acceptable solution because I will have scenario where I need to allow user to scroll content that is underneath the svg tag but still be able to place svg objects on top of it.

Comment: It does work in Safari 6

Comment: It does, but I need to support safari 5 :-)